# Hive UDF with Python - Runtime error

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I write a Hive Query that calls a UDF written in Python, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"psdr_doc_id":790892632}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"psdr_doc_id":790892632}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:143)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: or
```

I don't think it's anything to do with the Python function I have, since it works outside of Hive. Just by looking at the error, could anyone tell me what could possibly have gone wrong?
Please let me know if more information is needed.

The query I have is:

```
hive -e "select TRANSFORM(psdr_doc_id) using 'get_date.py' as published_date from test_table"
```

`get_date.py` prints out the date of publication of an article with its id (`psdr_doc_id`) as the input.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you try `select TRANSFORM(psdr_doc_id) using 'python get_date.py' as published_date from test_table`

Comment: I have tried that, doesn't work.